# Get users who have same properties (MySql query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as shown below and I want to search users who have vehicle "motorbike" AND "car", related to the tables, the search result should show only (1) john , not (3) mark, because I want "AND" not "OR".

How is it done with MySQL query ?

[image: JOIN 2 TABLES]

```
select * from members m left join properties p on m.user_id = p.user_id where concat_ws(',',property,value) in ('vehicle,motorbike','vehicle,car')
```

Comment: select * from members m left join properties p on m.user_id = p.user_id where concat_ws(',',property,value) in ('vehicle,motorbike','vehicle,car')

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
      A.user_id,
      name,
      property
FROM members A
INNER JOIN properties B
ON A.user_id=B.user_id
WHERE value IN ('motorbike','car')
GROUP BY A.user_id,name,property
HAVING COUNT(A.user_id)<>1
```

Comment: where is the keyword "vehicle" in your code? it is important, as the values may be same for property name of "vehicle" or "treasure" later

Comment: not work, the form is like this :
Search [ motorbike,car ] , Property [ vehicle ] (submit)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select name from members m, properties p where m.user_id=p.user_id and p.value="moterbike" and p.value="car";
```

Comment: while this code block might answer the question; you should try to improve your answer by adding relevant explanation to it. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

with respect,

I think some time it gives wrong result if we use having example because some time value can have 2 or more cars in same user

join example not retrieving any record

my answer is this

```
SELECT cc.*,mem.name
FROM
(SELECT user_id
FROM propoties
WHERE value='car') cc
JOIN
(SELECT userid
FROM properties
WHERE value='moterbyke') mb ON cc.userid=mb.userid
JOIN member mem ON cc.memberid=mem.memberid
```